# Lock Holder Preemption

Tags: multithreading

Could you have the following scenario in concurrent programs?

suppose a thread acquires a lock to execute a critical section.Then before the critical section is executed the processor preempts the thread. The new thread that comes for execution needs the lock from the old thread (that was preempted). So the current thread can't proceed (hangs until it get preempted). Is there a mechanism in Operating systems to not let threads preempted until the lock is released?

Comment: in linux spinlock, when a process tries to acquire the spinlock, it disables preemption first. so that kinds of deadlock cannot occur. For blocking lock (mutex), see Danel's answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for a thread holding a mutex to be preempted while executing a critical section. If the thread that the OS switches to tries to acquire that mutex and finds that it is already locked, then that thread should be context switched out immediately. The thread scheduler should be smart enough to not switch back to that thread until it has switched back to the thread holding the mutex and the mutex is released.

Comment: and when the mutex is released, the waiting thread goes into the run queue for later execution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing Kernel code then yes, there are mechanisms for preventing a thread to preempt.

For standard code there is no such thing. Some operations are atomic and are ensured atomic by the compiler and kernel but right after those operations the thread may be preempted and it can remain preempted for an undetermined amount of time (unless the system is a real-time sistem).